# Add computers to HP CM1312 NFI MFP Scanner

Tags: scanner

Does anyone happen to know how to add computers to the "Select Computer" menu of HP CM1312 NFI MFP Scanner?

I remember that there was a check box somewhere in the application but it didn't work reliably on all computers.

Isn't it possible to save scans on a network share or send them by e-mail?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by "Set up the product Scan Menu button"
take a look at [this](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01465702#AbT1)

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  External links can break, in which case this would be just a hint.  Can you add the essential information to your answer?  Use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.